# Counting a specific amount of yes/no based on changing value

Tags: excel, count

I'm sorry if this is a really simple questions, but I have not been able to find a solution.  I want/think I need to use the count function.  I have a column that contains `YES` and `NO`.  I want to set up an equation that will count the number of `YES` based on another number.  Then count the number of `NO` until reaching the #`YES`.  For example

```
    YES/NO       Count #YES       NO Result
      YES            3                5
      YES            5                6
      NO             7                7
      NO
      NO
      NO
      NO
      YES
      NO
      YES
      YES
      YES
      NO
      YES
```

Column `YES/NO` is given
Column `Count #YES` is given
Column `NO Result` is found

For the first go around, the function would count 3 `YES` in the `YES/NO` column.  Then count how many `NO` are in between the first `YES` and the 3rd `YES`.  There are 5 `NO` in this example.  For the second go around, the function would count 5 `YES`.  Then count how many `NO` are in between the first `YES` and 5th `YES`.  There are 6 `NO` in this example.

There wont actually be a `Count #YES` Column.  Instead this value will be stored in say `A1`.  This value will change (based on other criteria in my spreadsheet).

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this should do it. You can wrap this in `IFERROR` to handle the possibility of there not being enough instances of "YES" in the column, for example 8 in your sample data.

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$14)/($A$2:$A$15="YES"),B2)-B2
```

[image]

Comment: can I remove `15` and insert from `A2:A & end(xlup)`.  or do I have to use VBA for that?

Comment: `Range.End(xlUp)` is VBA, yes. Are you inserting the formula with VBA? Or are you looking to not "hard-code" the last row in the formula? I'm a bit confused what you're asking.

Comment: I do not want to use VBA for this.

Comment: You can extend the reference out past where your data ends, e.g. `=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$9999)/($A$2:$A$10000="YES"),B2)-B2`.

Comment: wait, what is the `15` for?

Comment: Is it not possible to do a Range.End(xlUp) without VBA?

Comment: I'm confused. How long is your column? I'm not sure why you're bringing up VBA at all. You don't need it. Not that I recommend it, but you could technically do `=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$1048575)/($A$2:$A$1048576="YES"),B2)-B2`.

Comment: its 62 rows long, but it could be more/less.  It will vary, but I guess it wont be over 500.  So using 10000 should be fine.

Comment: Okay.  could you please explain what the `15` is being used for?  The `15` right after `AGGREGATE`.

Comment: Yes, `15` corresponds to the `SMALL` functionality of the [`AGGREGATE`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) function. Basically, the formula finds the n-th instance of  "YES" and returns its position in the list, ignoring the "NO"s. Then it just subtracts `n` to get the count of "NO"s. *Formulas* > *Evaluate Function* gives you a nice walk-through. Let me know if it still is unclear and I can edit the answer with a more thorough explanation.

Comment: Okay, I kind of understand.  So `15` doesn't need to change?

Comment: Correct, it should not change. It's just a coincidence that the sample range went down to `A15`. The first `15` has nothing to do with the row number.

Comment: So why did you choose 15 and not say 10?

Comment: Because `10` corresponds to the `VAR.S` functionality of `AGGREGATE`. The first argument of `AGGREGATE` is a *function* number - 1 for `AVERAGE`, 2 for `COUNT`, 3 for `COUNTA` and so on. `AGGREGATE` applies a function to the list, and the `15` means I want to apply `SMALL` to the list.

Comment: Okay, I believe I understand now.

Comment: I've noticed that when I move my decimal place further out, it displays a number with decimals.  How would that be possible if YES's and NO's cannot be partials?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194574/discussion-between-bigben-and-zman3).

Answer (score 1):

I have applied the function in the attached workbook:

[Workbook](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1m_mefVZNSdQd_FNBFiYwBHXF2fszRjQj)

Used the below functions:

[image]

Then Match to get the Result:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: would you please show which ranges you are referring to from your equations?

Comment: You can have a look at the workbook I have attached with the intention that you can have a closer look.

Comment: Then should I assume that `D` should be `E` because you have nothing in column `D`.

Comment: Yes, you can remove that column.

Comment: this method works, but I like the other one posted by BigBen because it does not require an extra column to be calculated.  The simpler the better.   Thank you for the post.  I like to look at the different ways people solve problems.

Comment: Yes, that gives you answer with just one step.