# Change aggregate formula, outputting #NUM

Tags: excel, excel-formula, row, aggregate

I recently received a formula from a user here and needed to modify it because I realize that my data was a bit different from the example I gave.  I fixed for the most part, but ran into a new problem giving me an error of `#NUM!`.

I have a column of YES's and No's.  I wanted to count a specific amount of NO's and then match the count of YES's minus one.  Here is the formula the other user gave to me:

```
    AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($D$1:$D$9999)/($D$2:$D$10000="YES"),F2)-F2
```

Column D is my `YES/NO` column.
`F2` is a value, could be 5, could be 10.  It is dependent on other data within my sheet.

I realized shortly after implementing this into my sheet that I needed to switch `"YES"` to `"NO"`.  So I did so.  Well then I kept getting an error and then I realized that my `F2` was larger than the amount of `NO`s I had in column D.  So I added an `if` statement to combat that error, but I am still getting the error `#NUM!`.

```
    =IF(COUNTIF($D$2:$D$10000,"NO")>G2,COUNTIF($D$2:$D$10000,"YES"),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($D$1:$D$9999)/($D$2:$D$10000="NO"),F2)-F2)
```

Here is a sample of my data.  Let me know if you have any questions.

[image]

Cheers

Comment: Just use count to count the number of cells populated with text (even count "yes" & "no") and subtract the number of "yes"-1...

Comment: But the count depends on a specific number that changes.

Comment: So in the picture above, cell F2 will change automatically depending on other information in the other sheets I have.  I need to be able to reference that cell.

Comment: Why not check out the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56487606/4961700  Or include the iferror() as suggested.

Comment: okay, yes the `iferror` is much better and simpler.  Thank you for the suggestion.